# PHP Multiple HTTP headers in same file

Tags: php, xml, http, http-headers

I am writing a script which generates an XML file and prompt it for download. But at the same time i want to show some output to the user on the page like "compeleted successfully" or "here are errors".

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: What do you mean? To show if download is complete or if the file has stopped?

Comment: No it process some items to create the xml file. So some items could not be added to xml. I need to notify that.

Comment: Then notify the user before you pass the file to the browser. Use a form and put the button in it. If it's pushed, show the notifications.

Comment: If put anything other than xml on the file the xml becomes corrupted. Plus it doesn't output it. Because for download prompt the header is xml. That's why i am asking for multiple headers.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for multiple outputs in a single response. That is not possible.

You can create the XML and write it to a local file. Then output a HTML page with your message and a download link (and meta redirect) to the created XML file.